# flip effect with multiple backgrounds

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make flip effect of my background(like card flip) except the back face is always different depending on link clicked. Tried to make it in Jquery with changing the backface div before clicking the link but having lots of trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: What troubles are you facing? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Yep, a fiddle is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use two elements, front and back, and use `backface-visibility: hidden;` to hide the back of these elements. On click just change the rotation so that the hidden and the visible sides exchange and animate (by toggling class 'flip' or something):

```
<div class="click panel">
    <div class="front"><h2>Click Me!</div>
    <div class="back">check you on the flip side</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.panel > div {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel .front { 
    transform: rotateY(0deg);        
}
.panel.flip .front {  
    transform: rotateY(180deg);     
}
.panel .back{ 
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

}
.panel.flip .back{  
    transform: rotateY(0deg);     
}
```

jquery:

```
 $('.click').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('flip');});
```

You can change the content in the click function.
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/y6W49/7/

Comment: Thx, thats pretty much solves the question. From here i can move on :)

Comment: Glad I could help! I just skipped the prefixes, (-moz-,-webkit- etc) for readability, but you can find those in the jsfiddle.